# how to get a function to loop

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

This probably has a simple answer but I just can't think of one

I have a function f(n), I want the start value of n to be 63 and for f(63) to then become the new n and then the answer of that to become the new n and so on until it reaches 1.
I have tried to use a while loop but can't figure out how to get the answer of f(63) to become the new n

```
def f(n):
    if (n % 2)==0:
        return n/2
    else:
        return (3*n+1)/2
    q=63
while q != 1:
    print(f(q))
```

Comment: `n = f(63)`? what do you want, provide a sample input and output, also the function will never reach `q = 63` line and anything below that because it will always `return` before that

Comment: `while q != 1: q = f(q)` (this should be _outside_ of the function). Also, you may want to use `//` for integer division, otherwise floating point math might not be accurate enough for very large values of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `q=f(q)` so `q` becomes the new value. Something like this should work for you:

```
def f(n):
    if (n % 2)==0:
        return n/2
    else:
        return (3*n+1)/2
q=63
while q != 1:
    q=f(q)
    print(q)
```

Output:

```
95.0
143.0
215.0
323.0
...
```